# Amazon Athena - How can I exclude the metadata when create table based on query result

Tags: create-table, amazon-athena

In `Athena`, I want to create a table based on the query result, but every query result contains `2 files`, `".csv"` and `".csv.metadata"`. All these files are in my table and the metadata makes the table `looks messy`. Is there any way to `ignore` these `".csv.metadata"` files, only show the data of `".csv"` files?

Any suggestion or code snippets will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can exclude input files like this:

```
select * from your_table where "$PATH" not like '%metadata'
```

Comment: This worked for me with `select * from your_table where "$PATH" not like '%metadata'`

Comment: No idea why the moderator edited my post. The form `... is not ...` doesn't work on Athena/presto, but ` ... not ...` (without the `is`) does

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm using Athena engine version 2. Athena tries scanning the files anyway. Maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: Yes it will still scan the files, but it will filter out the rows in the output

Answer (score 7):

Adding an underscore at the beginning of the filename will cause Athena to ignore the file. For example: `_ignoredfile.csv.metadata`

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, works both for Hive and Athena and does not require end users to do anything.

Comment: Thanks! This answer led to another answer which explains that either an underscore or dot will cause Athena to ignore the file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53919491/3811916

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html):

> Athena reads all files in an Amazon S3 location you specify in the CREATE TABLE statement, and cannot ignore any files included in the prefix. When you create tables, include in the Amazon S3 path only the files you want Athena to read. Use AWS Lambda functions to scan files in the source location, remove any empty files, and move unneeded files to another location.

Comment: There is a workaround via the answer provided by Nicolas Busca

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround that may serve your needs is to create an Athena *view* that will filter our the "mess" in the table. You can then simply use the view instead of the table itself.